# Kubernetes - adding more nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I have a basic cluster, which has a `master` and `2 nodes`. The 2 nodes are part of an `aws autoscaling group - asg1`. These 2 nodes are running `application1`.

I need to be able to have further nodes, that are running `application2` be added to the cluster.

Ideally, I'm looking to maybe have a multi-region setup, whereby `aplication2` can be run in multiple regions, but be part of the same cluster (not sure if that is possible).

So my question is, how do I add nodes to a cluster, more specifically in `AWS`?

I've seen a couple of articles whereby people have spun up the instances and then manually logged in to install the kubeltet and various other things, but I was wondering if it could be done in more of an automatic way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you followed [this instructions](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/), you should have an autoscaling group for your minions.

Go to AWS panel, and scale up the autoscaling group. That should do it.

If you did it somehow manually, you can clone a machine selecting an existing minion/slave, and choosing "launch more like this".

Answer (score 0):

As Pablo said, you should be able to add new nodes (in the same availability zone) by scaling up your existing ASG. This will provision new nodes that will be available for you to run `application2`. Unless your applications can't share the same nodes, you may also be able to run `application2` on your existing nodes without provisioning new nodes if your nodes are big enough. In some cases this can be more cost effective than adding additional small nodes to your cluster.

To your other question, Kubernetes isn't designed to be run across regions. You can run a multi-zone configuration (in the same region) for higher availability applications (which is called Ubernetes Lite). Support for cross-region application deployments (Ubernetes) is currently being designed.